# Data hosting for a android application

Tags: java, android, hosting

i want to create a android application, where it will fetch stories (probably html or text) files from internet. i want to know where can host these files(no problem with paid service).

Users should be able to search the stories, rate , and options like mostread and NEW..etc

is there any predefined web services are available for this kind of purpose?

If NO, then what are the technologies i should be familier with to achieve this in a normal web server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you can try Amazon S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start with shared web hosting.
Starting at ~ $5/month, shared hosting offers usually have the following advantages:

- No need to set up yourself the linux system, Apache and MySQL server
- cPanel administration
- Support of your preferred server-side language: PHP, Python (less common than PHP) etc.
- Migrating to another host is pretty simple

The choice of the programming language + framework depends on your taste and experience.
Two very popular options are PHP/Code Igniter and Python/Django.

Of course, if the traffic becomes significant or if you already expect a very fast growth, you may also consider a scalable solution (which shared or even dedicated hosting is not). Amazon, Google and Microsoft provide this kind of service in the cloud.

From my personal experience with Amazon S3, setting up a web service in the could is far more time-consuming than with a traditional web host. I would not recommend it unless your traffic forecast is over dozens or hundreds of hits/second.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create your own service - checkout Google App Engine (GAE).

- Enabled Java deployment (no need to programming in PHP, Pythone etc.)
- Scalable (almost every one mobile app has potential to gain 1M users)
- free quotas (free start)
- Good integration with Google services and tools (GWT i.e.)

Disadvantages:

- There is no option to (easy) migrate your solution to other service.
- No ready to install apps (forums, etc).

Comment: thanks a lot for responses, I'm gonna go with GAE, as im familiar with java.